# FB Messenger cordova plugin

Tags: java, javascript, objective-c, cordova, facebook-messenger

I am having problems creating a Cordova plugin to establish a communication between a native application and a web view.

Facebook Messenger SDK was released for Android and iOS, which I can use to share content and so on. The hardest part is probably going to be triggering these methods from JavaScript.

Has anyone done this or can help me get this done?
I would be really grateful.

Is there an easier way to communicate without using Cordova at all? For example, listening to URLSchemes or something?

Comment: So you want to create a cordova plugin that uses the facebook messenger SDK? What content do you want to share between facebook users?

Comment: The SDK is limited to share pictures animated gifs and videos. I am currently building a cordova plugin myself. Doesnt seem to be too hard after all. I am sure there will be new problems as I am doing so.

Comment: did you find a solution for injecting facebook messenger into ionic app?